# split string on commas, ignore single quote and comma in single quote

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
10013751290,STUBBY'S GYM,HELLO ( Mate (, HEY 'duran,duran',this is [ possible[ ] ]possible ,1232424
```

I want to split by , using regex in java,  so the result I would be expecting is like

```
10013751290

STUBBY'S GYM

HELLO ( Mate (

HEY 'duran,duran'

this is [ possible[ ] ]possible

1232424
```

I tried the following expression `,(?=(?:[^']*\'[^']*\')*[^']*$)`

I am getting only 4 matches whereas I should be getting 6.

Please can some one help. I have checked and its not a duplicate, slightly different.

Comment: A naive way would be to split on quotes first and keep the empty entries, then split on commas each 2 results. This may work as long as you have an even number or quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to ignore a `'` that is an apostrophe, thus, you need to add this as an alternative to the pattern that matches any char but `'`, that is, `[^']` -> `(?:[^']|\b'\b)`. Or, `(?:[^']|(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z]))` or a fully Unicode `(?:[^']|(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L}))` (if supported) to only match `'` in between *alphabetic* chars, letters.

```java
\s*,\s*(?=(?:(?:(?:[^']|\b'\b)*'){2})*(?:[^']|\b'\b)*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DXoeb/1/). Details:

- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?=(?:(?:(?:[^']|\b'\b)*'){2})*(?:[^']|\b'\b)*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `(?:(?:(?:[^']|\b'\b)*'){2})*` - zero or more occurrences of two repetitions of

    - `(?:[^']|\b'\b)*` - zero or more occurrences of any char other than a `'` or a `'` in between any word chars
    - `'` - a single quotation mark
  - `(?:[^']|\b'\b)*` - zero or more occurrences of any char other than a `'` or a `'` in between any word chars
  - `$` - end of string.

Comment: fabulous this works, only thinng I forgot to add was 12345, ( 5678,1,2 ) , letters123 and should I ask another question, I need to include brackets as well and it should output as 12345 
(5678,1,2)
letters123, Is that possible at all?

Comment: @PrasadRamalingam I think you ask for a common workaround like `(?![^()]*\))`, see `\s*,(?![^()]*\))\s*(?=(?:(?:(?:[^']|\b'\b)*'){2})*(?:[^']|\b'\b)*$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DXoeb/2).

Comment: This works fab, Only thing I would say there is a loss of **space** in some of the matches, For eg  10013751290,STUBBY'S GYM,HELLO ( Mate (, HEY 'duran,duran',this is [ possible[ ] ]possible ,1232424,( 5678,1,2 ) , letters123 I would expect <SPACE>HEY 'duran, duran' and similarly ( 5678,1,2)<SPACE>, But I would still accept your answer as my question wasn't clear enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PrasadRamalingam Remove `\s*` if you need the spaces. Your expected output in the question hints at the fact you actually *want* to trim the matches.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this :

```
(?<=^|,)(((?:\s|\w)*'(?:\w|,)*')|.*?)(?=$|,)
```

result

```
10013751290
STUBBY'S GYM
HELLO ( Mate (
 HEY 'duran,duran'
this is [ possible[ ] ]possible 
1232424
```

[see demo](https://regex101.com/r/hFmIGZ/1)